# Square thumbnail advance

Tags: php, image, graphics, thumbnails

I have a php thumbnail function. How it works you can check below:

```
public static function makeThumb($source, $destination, $thumb_width){

        $size   = getimagesize($source);
        $width  = $size[0];
        $height = $size[1];
        $x      = 0;
        $y      = 0;

        $status  = false;

        if ($width > $height) {
            $x      = ceil(($width - $height) / 2);
            $width  = $height;
        } else if ($height > $width) {
            $y      = ceil(($height - $width) / 2);
            $height = $width;
        }

        $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width,$thumb_width) or die ('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');
        $extension = self::get_file_extension($source);
        if ($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'jpeg')
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
        if ($extension == 'gif')
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);
        if ($extension == 'png')
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

        imagecopyresampled($new_image,$image,0,0,$x,$y,$thumb_width,$thumb_width,$width,$height);


        if ($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'jpeg')
            $status = @imagejpeg($new_image, $destination);
        if ($extension == 'gif')
            $status = @imagegif($new_image, $destination);  
        if ($extension == 'png')
            $status = @imagepng($new_image, $destination);      

        imagedestroy($image);

        return $status;
    }
```

Please check images below (how it works):

[image: Original image]
[image: Thumbnail image result]

Question: How can I get this image as a result (This thumb is from photoshop)?

[image: I need this thumb]

Comment: use php [imagick library](http://php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php) for multiple options.

Comment: I know, but need GD solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right solution is here:

```
public static function makeThumb($source, $destination, $square_size=167, $quality=90) {

        $status  = false;
        list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($source);

        if($width> $height) {
           $width_t =  $square_size;
           $height_t    =   round($height/$width*$square_size);
           $off_y       =   ceil(($width_t-$height_t)/2);
           $off_x       =   0;

        } elseif($height> $width) {

           $height_t    =   $square_size;
           $width_t =   round($width/$height*$square_size);
           $off_x       =   ceil(($height_t-$width_t)/2);
           $off_y       =   0;

        } else {

            $width_t    =   $height_t   =   $square_size;
            $off_x      =   $off_y      =   0;
        }

        $thumb_p    = imagecreatetruecolor($square_size, $square_size);

        $extension  = self::get_file_extension($source);

        if($extension == "gif" or $extension == "png"){

            imagecolortransparent($thumb_p, imagecolorallocatealpha($thumb_p, 0, 0, 0, 127));
            imagealphablending($thumb_p, false);
            imagesavealpha($thumb_p, true);
        }   

        if ($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'jpeg')
            $thumb = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
        if ($extension == 'gif')
            $thumb = imagecreatefromgif($source);
        if ($extension == 'png')
            $thumb = imagecreatefrompng($source);

        $bg = imagecolorallocate ( $thumb_p, 255, 255, 255 );
        imagefill ($thumb_p, 0, 0, $bg);

        imagecopyresampled($thumb_p, $thumb, $off_x, $off_y, 0, 0, $width_t, $height_t, $width, $height);

        if ($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'jpeg')
            $status = @imagejpeg($thumb_p,$destination,$quality);
        if ($extension == 'gif')
            $status = @imagegif($thumb_p,$destination,$quality);
        if ($extension == 'png')
            $status = @imagepng($thumb_p,$destination,9);

        imagedestroy($thumb);
        imagedestroy($thumb_p);

        return $status;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of the wrong thumbwidth (and no thumbheight!) is what gives you this square result.

```
 imagecopyresampled($new_image,$image,0,0,$x,$y,$thumb_width,$thumb_width,$width,$height);
```

According to the PHP manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php), imagecopyresampled copies a resized region of the original image. But you want the whole original. You could do

```
 imagecopyresampled($new_image,$image,0,0,0,0,$thumb_width,$thumb_height,$width,$height);
```

You need to calculate $thumbheight first - height*thumbwidth/width would do, or you could divide the original width and height by a set amount.

As the comments below show, the parameters used in this function are rather confusing. So I add an explanation in the hope that you can create what you like.

`imagecopyresampled` copies and resizes a rectangular part of an image into a rectangular part of a new one. So all the parameters are needed twice over - for the original and the new image. A drawing might help:

```
      $image                  $new_image                
+----------------+        +----------------+
|   source img   |        | destination img|
|                |        |                |
|                |        |    +--------+  |
|        +------+|        |    |  part  |  |
|        | part ||        |    |  copy  |  |
|        |      ||        |    +--------+  |
|        +------+|        |                |
+----------------+        +----------------+
```

The arguments are

```
   $dst_image        the new image (dst = destination)
   $src_image        the old image (src = source)
   $dst_x , $dst_y   top left of destination area
   $src_x , $src_y   top left of source area
   $dst_w , $dst_h   width and height of destination area
   $src_w , $src_h   width and height of source area
```

If you're trying to copy the whole source image, to a new size, in a new destination image, they will be something like

```
   $dst_image        the new image (dst = destination)
   $src_image        the old image (src = source)
   0 , 0             top left of destination area
   0 , 0             top left of source area
   $dst_w , $dst_h   new width and height of thumb
   $width , $height  width and height of whole source image
```

But as I'm not certain what size you want the thumbnail, I have to leave you to find the correct values.

Comment: If it needs to be square and look like your photoshop example, then no, I don't have a solution either :)

Comment: I'm trying to say - your photoshop is rectangular, but you say you want a square image. So I can't work it out. But I've expanded my answer to explain how the parameters work more clearly. Hopefully that gives you the means to work it out.